# Equation of the tangent of the curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I want to find the equation of the tangent of the curve $f(x,y)=x^5+x^4+y^2$ at $(0,0)$.

I have tried the following:

$\nabla f (x,y)=(5x^4+4x^3, 2y)$

$\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$

The equation of the tangent is given by the relation: $\nabla f(0,0) \cdot (x-0, y-0)=0 \Rightarrow (0,0) \cdot (x,y)=0 \Rightarrow 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot y=0$

Could you tell me if it is right? If so, which the equation of the tangent?

**Edit:**

There is an example with tangent in my notes: The tangents of $f(x,y)=-4x^2y^2+(x^2+y^2)^3$ at $(0,0)$ are $x=0$ and $y=0$. The tangents of $g(x,y)=-y^3+3x^2y+(x^2+y^2)^2$ at $(0,0)$ are $y=0, \sqrt{3} x+y=0, \sqrt{3} x-y=0$.

How can I find it in this case?

Comment: Do you mean the tangent plane to the graph of $f?$

Comment: @mfl There is an example with tangent in my notes: The tangents of $f(x,y)=-4x^2y^2+(x^2+y^2)^3$ at $(0,0)$ are $x=0$ and $y=0$. The tangents of $g(x,y)=-y^3+3x^2y+(x^2+y^2)^2$ at $(0,0)$ are $y=0, \sqrt{3} x+y=0, \sqrt{3} x-y=0$. How is it in this case?

Comment: From your example, it seems that you are looking at the curve $f(x, y) = 0$. However, $f(x,y) = y^2 + x^4(1-x)$. That is, $f(x,y) > 0$ close to the origing, except for the point $(0,0)$. So if you're looking at the real curve, then all lines through the origin are tangents.

Comment: @Raclette I want to find the equation of the tangent, because I am trying to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the curves $f$ and $g$. Could you have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052007/do-they-intersect-transversally ?