# Intersection multiplicity of the curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I want to find the intersection multiplicity of the curves $f(x,y)=x^5+x^4+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^6-x^5+y^2$ at the point $P=(0,0)$.

That`s what I have tried:

$f$ and $g$ have a common tangent, the $y=0$.

So $I(P, f\cap g) > m_P(f) \cdot m_P(g)=4$

$$f(x, 0)=x^5+x^4 \Rightarrow s=\deg f(x, 0)=5$$

$$g(x, 0)=x^6-x^5 \Rightarrow r =\deg g(x, 0)=6$$

$$s \leq r$$

So we consider $h(x, y)=g(x, y)-x f(x, y)$

$$h(x, y)=x^6-x^5+y^2-x(x^5+x^4+y^2)=x^6-x^5+y^2-x^6-x^5-xy^2 \\ \Rightarrow h(x, y)=-2x^5+y^2-xy^2$$

$\deg h(x, 0)=5<r$

So $I(P, f\cap g)=I(P,f\cap h)$

$$f(x,0)=x^5+x^4\Rightarrow \deg f(x,0)=5=s$$

$$h(x,0)=-2x^5\Rightarrow \deg h(x,0)=5=p$$

They have a common tangent, $x=0$, so they don`t intersect traverrsally.

We consider the polynomial $$h_1(x,y)=h(x,y)+2f(x,y)=3y^2-xy^2+2x^4$$

$deg h_1(x,0)=4<s,p$

So, $I(P, f\cap h)=I(P,f\cap h_1)$

$f(x,0)=x^5+x^4 \Rightarrow \deg f(x,0)=5=s$

$h_1(x,0)=2x^4\Rightarrow \deg h_1(x,0)=4=t$

They have a common tangent $x=0$,so they don`t intersect traversally.
We consider the polynomial $h_2(x,y)=2f(x,y)-xh_1(x,y)=2x^4+2y^2-3xy^2+x^2y^2$

$\deg h_2(x,0)=4<s$

So $I(P, f\cap h_1)=I(P,  h_1\cap h_2)$

$h_1(x,0)=2x^4\Rightarrow \deg h_1(x,0)=4=s$

$h_2(x,0)=2x^4\Rightarrow \deg h_2(x,0)=4=m$

They have a common tangent $x=0$, so they don`t intersect traversally.

We consider the polynomial $h_3(x,y)=h_1(x,y)-h_2(x,y)=y^2(1+2x-x^2)$

$\deg h_3(x,0)=0<s,m$

So $I(P,h_1\cap h_2)=I(P,h_2\cap h_3)$

$h_2(x,0)=2x^4\Rightarrow \deg h_2(x,0)=4=m$

$h_3(x,0)=0\Rightarrow \deg h_3(x,9)=9=n$

So $I(P,h_2\cap h_3)=I(P,h_2\cap y^2)+I(P,h_2\cap (1+2x-x^2))$

$I(P,h_2\cap y^2)=8$

$I(h_2\cap (1+2x-x^2))=0$

Therefore, $I(P, f \cap g)=8$.

Is it right? Do we find that $f$ and $h$ have a common tangent from $f(x,0)$ and $h(x,0)$ ?

Comment: Check their derivatives at the intersection point.

Comment: @Arthur I edited my post... Could you tell me if we can do it like that?

Comment: I would have thought that the definition of a transversal intersection includes that the curves have a (unique) tangent at the point of intersection? May be I'm wrong? Mind you, if you are only interested in real points, your former curve has darn few near the origin :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In my notes, there is the following example:
$$f(x,y)=-4x^2y^2+(x^2+y^2)^3 \\ g(x,y)=-y^3+3x^2y+(x^2+y^2)^2$$
The equations of the tangents at $P=(0,0)$:
$$\text{ of } f: x=0, y=0$$
$$\text{ of } g: y(3x^2-y^2)=0 \Rightarrow y=0, \sqrt{3}x-y=0,  \sqrt{3}x+y=0 $$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is the way I did it wrong?

Comment: I don't know. If you define a tangent as a factor of the lowest degree form of the Taylor expansion, then it sure looks like your calculation proves that the two polynomials share $y=0$. I don't have your context, so cannot tell for sure. In a calculus course I would be very worried about $f$ having no othe zeros in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. OTOH the "double" tangent $y=0$ is a calculus method killer usually, and you did tag this with algebraic geometry. Check with your teacher. I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edited my post... I found the tangents.. Could you explain me how we could find the intersection multiplicity of the curves?

Comment: Are these surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $z=f(x,y)$ and $z=g(x,y)$ or are these curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$? I can see by some comments that these are curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, that is not clear from the question.

Comment: @robjohn We have that $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $P \in \mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If I had to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the $g(x,y)=xy^2+x^4$ and $h(x,y)=x^2y-x^4$ curves, then these curves do not have tangents in common and so I can use $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)$ to get to that $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)=3\cdot 3=9$?

Comment: @user402543 Don't those two curves share both axes as tangents at the origin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number#Intersection_multiplicities_for_plane_curves) for the definining properties of the intersection property. These allow us to compute:

$~~~I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,x^6-x^5+y^2)\\
=I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,(x^6-x^5+y^2)-(x^5+x^4+y^2))\\
=I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,x^4 (x^2-2x-1))\\
=I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,x^4)+I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,x^2-2x-1)\\
=I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2,x^4)\\
=I_P(y^2,x^4)\\
=2 \cdot 4  \cdot I_P(y,x)\\
=8$

Comment: Could you explain me how you concluded that $I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2, x^2-2x-1)=0$ and why $I_P(x^5+x^4+y^2, x^4)=I_{P}(y^2,x^4)$ ?

Comment: 1) $x^2-2x-1$ doesn't vanish at $P$. 2) $x^5+x^4$ is a multiple of $x^4$.

Comment: I understand!!! Thank you very much!!!
$$$$
I want to ask you something about the following identity :

If $f=f_1^{r_1} \cdot f_2^{r_2} \cdots f_s^{r_s}, g=g_1^{t_1} \cdot g_2^{t_2} \cdots g_r^{t_r} $, then:

$$I(P, f \cap g)=\sum_{i,j} r_i t_j I(P, f_i \cap g_j) $$

Could you give me an example where the factorizations of $f,g$ have more than one term?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If I had to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the $g(x,y)=xy^2+x^4$ and $h(x,y)=x^2y-x^4$ curves, then these curves do not have tangents in common and so I can use $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)$ to get to that $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)=3\cdot 3=9$?

Comment: @user402543 Better ask this as a separate question. :)

Answer (score 2):

$ f(x,y) =0 $ (red curve) has *no real* common tangent with $ g(x,y) =0 $ (blue curve) at $ P(0,0) $.

[image]

Comment: If I had to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the $g(x,y)=xy^2+x^4$ and $h(x,y)=x^2y-x^4$ curves, then these curves do not have tangents in common and so I can use $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)$ to get to that $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)=3\cdot 3=9$?

Answer (score 1):

From the system of equations,

$$x^5+x^4+y^2=x^6-x^5+y^2=0,$$

you can eliminate $y$, and

$$-x^6+2x^5+x^4=0.$$

This polynomial has a quadruple root at $0$.

Comment: So, if we want to find the intersection multiplicity of two curves, do we set the two curves equal?
$$$$
Also, is that what I have done wrong?

Comment: If you want to study the intersection of two curves, well, intersect them...

Comment: And how do we continue?

$$$$
Also, I edited my post.. Could you tell me if it is right and if we found the tangents like that?

Comment: @YvesDaoust If I had to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the $g(x,y)=xy^2+x^4$ and $h(x,y)=x^2y-x^4$ curves, then these curves do not have tangents in common and so I can use $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)$ to get to that $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)=3\cdot 3=9$?